# Try opening a file as an archive, otherwise read as a regular file

Tags: python, file, archive, bzip2

I am trying to process a list of files, where each may be a regular text file OR a bz2 archive.

How can I use try-except blocks most efficiently to attempt to open each file in the appropriate format? I would rather not check the file's extension, as this cannot always be relied upon (and is not very EAFP).

Currently I am doing:

```
def data_generator(*corpora):
    def parse_lines(fobj):
        for line in fobj:
            # Do lots of processing.
            # ...
            # Many lines here omitted.
            yield ('lots', 'of', 'data')

    for corpus in corpora:
        try:
            with bz2.BZ2File(corpus, mode='r') as f:
                for data in parse_lines(f):
                    yield data
        except IOError:
            with codecs.open(corpus, encoding='utf-8') as f:
                for data in parse_lines(f):
                    yield data
```

I think the repeated `for data in parse_lines(f): ...` code looks superfluous, but I can't think of a way to get rid of it. Is there any way to reduce the previous, or is there another way to try to "smart open" a file?

#### Edit: Optional followup

What would be an appropriate way to scale up the number of formats checked? As an example, the program 7zip allows you to right-click on any file and attempt to open it as an archive (any that 7zip supports). With the current try-except block strategy, it seems like you would start getting nested in blocks pretty quickly even after just a few formats, like:

```
try:
    f = ...
except IOError:
    try:
        f = ...
    except IOError:
        try:
            ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really just the duplicate loops that have got you concerned, you could move `f` out of the scope of the try-catch block, then put a single copy of the loop after everything's said and done:

```
try:
    f = bz2.BZ2File(corpus, mode='r')
except IOError:
    f = codecs.open(corpus, encoding='utf-8')
for data in parse_lines(f):
    yield data
f.close()
```

Although I'd look into only opening the file once, checking for the BZ2 header (the characters `BZ` as the first two bytes), and using that to decide whether to continue reading it as plaintext, or pass the data into a `bz2.BZ2Decompressor` instance.